# python: adding rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to read a dataframe, evaluate a condition based on 2 columns values then create a new line after the current i'm reading and apply the condition on this new one.

Here the dataframe:

```
{'MColumn':     a            b          c     d
0              201607        1924       1927  1924
1              202103        2166       2170  2166
2              201906        2075       2079  2075
```

pseudo code:

```
for i in len(MColumn):
    #reading the first line: 201607   1924    1927  1924
    if b<=d then:
        #create new line with values: 201607   1924    1927  1925
    #next loop has to apply the condition on the new line inserted
```

Final dataframe:

```
{'MColumn':     a            b          c     d
0              201607        1924       1927  1924
1              201607        1924       1927  1925
2              201607        1924       1927  1926
3              201607        1924       1927  1927
4              202103        2166       2170  2166
5              202103        2166       2170  2167
6              202103        2166       2170  2168
7              202103        2166       2170  2169
8              202103        2166       2170  2170
9              201906        2075       2079  2075
10              201906        2075       2079  2076
11              201906        2075       2079  2077
12              201906        2075       2079  2078
13              201906        2075       2079  2079
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, dataframes are not optimised to be looped over, so your code would be more efficient as a list of (lists, or tuples, or dicts). Secondly, in your pseudocode, don't you mean d<=c?

Comment: yes exactly you are right, the condition is d<=c. So any suggestion in python to do that?

Comment: @DobbyTheElf could you help me sending a python example able to do that job? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy not using DataFrames due to the efficiency reason I suggested, then the following code

```
data = [
    {"a": 201607, "b": 1924, "c": 1927, "d": 1924},
    {"a": 202103, "b": 2166, "c": 2170, "d": 2166},
    {"a": 201906, "b": 2075, "c": 2079, "d": 2075},
]
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if line["d"] < line["c"]:
        data.insert(
            i + 1, {"a": line["a"], "b": line["b"], "c": line["c"], "d": line["d"] + 1}
        )
print(data)
```

produces (I've improved the formatting):

```
[
    {'a': 201607, 'b': 1924, 'c': 1927, 'd': 1924},
    {'a': 201607, 'b': 1924, 'c': 1927, 'd': 1925},
    {'a': 201607, 'b': 1924, 'c': 1927, 'd': 1926},
    {'a': 201607, 'b': 1924, 'c': 1927, 'd': 1927},
    {'a': 202103, 'b': 2166, 'c': 2170, 'd': 2166},
    {'a': 202103, 'b': 2166, 'c': 2170, 'd': 2167},
    {'a': 202103, 'b': 2166, 'c': 2170, 'd': 2168},
    {'a': 202103, 'b': 2166, 'c': 2170, 'd': 2169},
    {'a': 202103, 'b': 2166, 'c': 2170, 'd': 2170},
    {'a': 201906, 'b': 2075, 'c': 2079, 'd': 2075},
    {'a': 201906, 'b': 2075, 'c': 2079, 'd': 2076},
    {'a': 201906, 'b': 2075, 'c': 2079, 'd': 2077},
    {'a': 201906, 'b': 2075, 'c': 2079, 'd': 2078},
    {'a': 201906, 'b': 2075, 'c': 2079, 'd': 2079}
]
```